# $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |(-ax^2 + \mathrm{i}bx + c)^{-1}|^2 \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-integration

In D. E. Newland's book, *An Introduction to Random Vibrations, Spectral & Wavelet Analysis*, there is an integral of the form
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left|\frac{1}{-ax^2 + \mathrm{i}bx + c}\right|^2 \mathrm{d}x,
$$
the solution of which is given as $\pi/bc$. The reader is pointed to a reference where a proof is given using Cauchy's residue theorem. Is this the only way to prove it or is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: here $i = \sqrt{-1}$, correct?

Comment: no it must be $$i^2=-1$$

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ real or complex?

Comment: Partial fraction expansion works.

Comment: Setting $a=-1$ and $c=1$, and letting $b\to0$, yields a convergent integral, while the claimed answer tends to $\infty$.

Comment: @Chappers, $a, b, c$ are real.

Comment: I think you want to assume $b c > 0$, because the integral certainly isn't going to be negative.

Comment: In fact, better make $a, b, c > 0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, yes, $a, b, c > 0$ in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left|(c-ax^2)+i(bx)\right|^2 = (c-ax^2)^2 + b^2x^2$, hence the given integral equals

$$ I(a,b,c)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{a^2 x^4 + (b^2-2ac) x^2 + c^2} $$
and since
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial a}\,I(a,b,c) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{2 c x^2-2 a x^4}{\left(c^2+(b^2-2 a c) x^2+a^2 x^4\right)^2}\,dx = 0 $$
it follows that
$$ I(a,b,c)=\lim_{a\to 0^+} I(a,b,c) \stackrel{\text{DCT}}{=} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{b^2 x^2+c^2}=\frac{\pi}{bc} $$
as claimed. The only non-trivial part is to notice that the given integral does not really depend on $a$.
I am assuming $a,b,c>0$ to avoid sign issues and $\text{DCT}$ stands for Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: This should be for $a, b, c > 0$.  $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial a} I(a,b,c) > 0$ if $a < 0 < c$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: correct. Answer fixed.

Comment: It converges perfectly well if $a, b$ and/or $c$ is negative (as long as they are nonzero).  That's not the reason you want to assume positivity.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am new to DCT, but in the last row, does it apply to the second equality and not the first?

Comment: @adipro: the first equality is a consequence of $\frac{\partial I}{\partial a}=0$, i.e. of the fact that the integral does not really depend on $a$.